# How to create pointers for subclasses in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, subclass, c++builder-xe7, appmethod

I'm with a little trouble  when pointing to a subclass of an API.

Here is the original pascal code of what am I trying to do:

```
  Adapter:=TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter;
  remoteDevice:=Adapter.getRemoteDevice(stringtojstring(targetMACAddress));
  sock:=remoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UID);
```

Reduced version of it:

```
sock:=TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter.getRemoteDevice(stringtojstring(targetMACAddress)).createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UID);
```

Here I have what I've already tried to do:

```
  _di_JBluetoothSocket* sock = new _di_JBluetoothSocket;
  sock = &TJBluetoothAdapter::JavaClass->getDefaultAdapter()->getRemoteDevice(StringToJString(targetMACAddress))->createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uid);
```

and:

```
  TJBluetoothAdapter::JavaClass->getDefaultAdapter()->getRemoteDevice(StringToJString(targetMACAddress))->createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uid)* sock;
```

and:

```
  TJBluetoothAdapter* sock;
  sock = TJBluetoothAdapter::JavaClass->getDefaultAdapter()->getRemoteDevice(StringToJString(targetMACAddress))->createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uid);
```

However I always get error when compilling, what should I do?
Since now, thanks for your advice.

Comment: What error do you get? It's not very helpful to omit that.

Comment: Which language is this?  There is no `:=` operator in the C++ language.  Maybe BNF?

Comment: As I said in the question, the first and the second snippets are originally Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your `sock` variable incorrectly.  Do not declare a pointer to a `_di_...` class type.  It is *already* a pointer (more specifically, it is a typedef for the [`System::DelphiInterface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Delphi_Interfaces) class, which is a C++ [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) wrapper around a Delphi interface pointer).

```
_di_JBluetoothAdapter Adapter = TJBluetoothAdapter::JavaClass->getDefaultAdapter();
_di_JBluetoothDevice remoteDevice = Adapter->getRemoteDevice(StringToJString(targetMACAddress));
_di_JBluetoothSocket sock = remoteDevice->createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UID);
```

Which is roughly equivalent to this:

```
JBluetoothAdapter *Adapter = TJBluetoothAdapter::JavaClass->getDefaultAdapter();
Adapter->AddRef();

JBluetoothDevice *remoteDevice = Adapter->getRemoteDevice(StringToJString(targetMACAddress));
remoteDevice->AddRef();

JBluetoothSocket *sock = remoteDevice->createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UID);
sock->AddRef();

...

sock->_Release();
remoteDevice->_Release();
Adapter->_Release();
```